# Output a Vector Element of Enum Class Type in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have created card and deck classes for use in a C++ poker game, however, I'm trying to check that my assignment of vector elements are correct and having issues displaying them on the console. I have an enumerated class for the suits and integer values for the ranks. I see that my deck vector is generating with 52 cards, but I'm not sure how to correctly get this to display on the screen using the card class `display()` function for each vector element. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm also guessing an alternate method would be to overload the output stream operator to display a vector element that is an object with an enumerated class parameter, but also not sure on what that syntax would look like.

```
int main(){ Deck deck();}
```

**Card.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Suit { Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs };

class Card
{
private:
    Suit m_suit;
    int m_rank;
public:
    Card();
    Card(int r, Suit s);
    void display();

    int getRank();
    void setRank(int);

    Suit getSuit();
    void setSuit(Suit);

};
```

**Card.cpp**

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


Card::Card(): m_rank(0), m_suit(Suit::Hearts)
{
    
}


Card::Card(int r, Suit s)
{
    m_rank = r;
    m_suit = s;
}

void Card::display()
{
    if (m_rank == 1)    // for number cards, show value
    {
        std::cout << "Ace";
    }
    else if ((2 <= m_rank) && (m_rank <= 10))
    {
        std::cout << m_rank;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (m_rank)
        {
        case 11:
            std::cout << "Jack";
            break;
        case 12:
            std::cout << "Queen";
            break;
        case 13:
            std::cout << "King";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "INVALID RANK";

        }
    }

    switch (m_suit)         // display suit
    {
    case Suit::Hearts:
        std::cout << " of Hearts";
        break;
    case Suit::Diamonds:
        std::cout << " of Diamonds";
        break;
    case Suit::Spades:
        std::cout << " of Spades";
        break;
    case Suit::Clubs:
        std::cout << " of Clubs";
        break;

    };
}

int Card::getRank()
// return the numeric value of a card
{
    return (m_rank);
}
```

**Deck.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"
class Deck
{
private:
    Card card;
    std::vector<Card> m_deck;
public:
    Deck();
    void shuffle();
    void grabCard();
};
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>

Deck::Deck()
{
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
    {
        for (int j = int(Suit::Hearts); j <= int(Suit::Clubs); j++)
        {
            m_deck.push_back(Card(int(i), Suit(j))); //passing the card constructor to create a card object, then store it as a vector element
            int counter = 0; // use to print out each element
            std::cout << m_deck[card.display()]; //output each card obect via display method
            std::cout << "\t\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
void Deck::shuffle()
{
    

}
void Deck::grabCard()
{

}
```

Comment: Aside -- if you are actually playing poker, the suits are ranked, in descending order of precedence, Space, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs... See also - [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin good tip! I'll adjust them in the enumerations list as the proper value order assigned might come in handy for determining hands. As for using namespace std, I began removing it certain places and forget it card.h, but you are correct on it being bad practice!

Comment: Yes, I saw that in Card.cpp. It's good to start with good habits -- it's much easier than breaking bad ones later `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display vector element, you should call `display()` of the vector element to display.

```
std::cout << m_deck[card.display()];
```

should be

```
m_deck.back().display();
```

to have it display the last pushed card.

Also `int main(){ Deck deck();}` is a main function with only function declaration and `Deck::Deck()` won't be called.
To call the constructor, it should be `int main(){ Deck deck;}`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I incorrectly typed the main function into the question box, but you are correct.